# Boost::bind compile error when trying to set member function for boost::::asio::deadline_timer

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding the compile errors I'm getting when trying to create a boost::asio::deadline_timer.  I get the errors below with the following code example on MSVC10.  It was built with Boost 1.48

The first error looks like it is complaining about a member function set as a handler to async_wait being a reference.  However,  when I change the argument it gives a similar error.

I've been looking at Boost::Bind and Boost::Asio to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong.  My code is similar to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) example with the way I use bind and deadline_timer.

Sorry about how messy the compile errors look.  I'm still trying to get a handle on Markdown.

### Code Example

## include

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class TimerThing
{
protected:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* statusTimer_;
    boost::thread_group worker_threads_;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;

public:
    TimerThing() {}

    virtual ~TimerThing(){}

    void updateStatus(boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            return;

        std::cout<<"Status Update"<<std::endl;

        statusTimer_->expires_at(statusTimer_->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        statusTimer_->async_wait(boost::bind(&TimerThing::updateStatus, this, , boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void start()
    {
        statusTimer_=new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service_);
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> myWork(new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service_));
        work_=myWork;

        worker_threads_.create_thread( boost::bind( &TimerThing::threadAction, this ) );

        statusTimer_->expires_at(statusTimer_->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        statusTimer_->async_wait(boost::bind(&TimerThing::updateStatus, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void threadAction()
    {
        io_service_.run();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        work_.reset();
        io_service_.stop();
        worker_threads_.join_all();

        delete statusTimer_;
    }

};



#include "TimerThing.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    TimerThing t;

    std::string input;
    std::cout<<"Press f to stop"<<std::endl;

    t.start();

    std::cin>>input;

    t.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

### Compiler errors

c:\Underware\version\include\boost/bind/bind.hpp(313): error C2664: 'R boost::_mfi::mf1::operator ()(const U &,A1) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const boost::system::error_code' to 'boost::system::error_code &'

> ```
>      with
>      [
>          R=void,
>          T=TimerThing,
>          A1=boost::system::error_code &,
>          U=TimerThing *
>      ]
>      Conversion loses qualifiers
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/bind/bind_template.hpp(47) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::_bi::list2<A1,A2>::operator ()<F,boost::_bi::list1<const boost::system::error_code &>>(boost::_bi::type<T>,F &,A &,int)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          A1=boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,
>          A2=boost::arg<1>,
>          F=boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,
>          T=void,
>          A=boost::_bi::list1<const boost::system::error_code &>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp(46) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>::operator ()<const Arg1>(const A1 &)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          R=void,
>          F=boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,
>          L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>,
>          Arg1=const boost::system::error_code,
>          A1=const boost::system::error_code
>      ]
>
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp(45) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::asio::detail::binder1<Handler,Arg1>::operator ()(void)'
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Arg1=boost::system::error_code
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/wait_handler.hpp(59) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::asio::detail::binder1<Handler,Arg1>' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Arg1=boost::system::error_code
>      ]
>
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/wait_handler.hpp(45) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::asio::detail::wait_handler<Handler>::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::io_service_impl *,boost::asio::detail::operation *,const boost::system::error_code &,size_t)'
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp(185) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::asio::detail::wait_handler<Handler>' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/deadline_timer_service.hpp(137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::async_wait<WaitHandler>(boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::implementation_type &,Handler)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          Time_Traits=boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>,
>          WaitHandler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp(502) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<TimeType,TimeTraits>::async_wait<WaitHandler>(boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::implementation_type &,const WaitHandler &)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          TimeType=boost::posix_time::ptime,
>          TimeTraits=boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>,
>          WaitHandler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Time_Traits=boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>
>      ]
> ```

c:\users\tharper\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\asiotimer\asiotimer\TimerThing.h(48) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer::async_wait>(const WaitHandler &)' being compiled

> ```
>      with
>      [
>          Time=boost::posix_time::ptime,
>          R=void,
>          F=boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,
>          L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>,
> ```
>
> WaitHandler=boost::_bi::bind_t,boost::_bi::list2,boost::arg<1>>>
>            ]
>    TimerThing.cpp

c:\Underware\version\include\boost/bind/bind.hpp(313): error C2664: 'R boost::_mfi::mf1::operator ()(const U &,A1) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const boost::system::error_code' to 'boost::system::error_code &'

> ```
>      with
>      [
>          R=void,
>          T=TimerThing,
>          A1=boost::system::error_code &,
>          U=TimerThing *
>      ]
>      Conversion loses qualifiers
> ```

c:\Underware\version\include\boost/bind/bind_template.hpp(47) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::_bi::list2::operator ()>(boost::_bi::type,F &,A &,int)' being compiled

> ```
>      with
>      [
>          A1=boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,
>          A2=boost::arg<1>,
>          F=boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,
>          T=void,
>          A=boost::_bi::list1<const boost::system::error_code &>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp(46) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>::operator ()<const Arg1>(const A1 &)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          R=void,
>          F=boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,
>          L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<>>,
>          Arg1=const boost::system::error_code,
>          A1=const boost::system::error_code
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp(45) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::asio::detail::binder1<Handler,Arg1>::operator ()(void)'
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Arg1=boost::system::error_code
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/wait_handler.hpp(59) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::asio::detail::binder1<Handler,Arg1>' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Arg1=boost::system::error_code
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/wait_handler.hpp(45) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::asio::detail::wait_handler<Handler>::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::io_service_impl *,boost::asio::detail::operation *,const boost::system::error_code &,size_t)'
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp(185) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::asio::detail::wait_handler<Handler>' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/deadline_timer_service.hpp(137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::async_wait<WaitHandler>(boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::implementation_type &,Handler)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          Time_Traits=boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>,
>          WaitHandler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Handler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>
>      ]
>      c:\Underware\version\include\boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp(502) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<TimeType,TimeTraits>::async_wait<WaitHandler>(boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::implementation_type &,const WaitHandler &)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          TimeType=boost::posix_time::ptime,
>          TimeTraits=boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>,
>          WaitHandler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>,
>          Time_Traits=boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>
>      ]
>      c:\users\tharper\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\asiotimer\asiotimer\TimerThing.h(48) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<Time>::async_wait<boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>>(const WaitHandler &)' being compiled
>      with
>      [
>          Time=boost::posix_time::ptime,
>          R=void,
>          F=boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,
>          L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>,
>          WaitHandler=boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,TimerThing,boost::system::error_code &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<TimerThing *>,boost::arg<1>>>
>      ]
> ```

Comment: `void updateStatus(boost::system::error_code& ec)` should be void `updateStatus(const boost::system::error_code& ec)`. And you have extra comma in `boost::bind(&TimerThing::updateStatus, this, , boost::asio::placeholders::error));`

Comment: @IgorR. THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!
The const was the issue.  You should turn the comment into an answer so you can get credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void updateStatus(boost::system::error_code& ec)` should be `void updateStatus(const boost::system::error_code& ec)`.

And you have extra comma in `boost::bind(&TimerThing::updateStatus, this, , boost::asio::placeholders::error));`

Answer (score 2):

Your bind in `start` is correct, the one in `updateStatus` is not:

```
void updateStatus(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
        return;

    std::cout<<"Status Update"<<std::endl;

    statusTimer_->expires_at(
      statusTimer_->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    statusTimer_->async_wait(
      boost::bind(&TimerThing::updateStatus, this, 
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

You need to use the placeholder as well.

A general hint: Prefer posting compilable examples instead of a full compiler barf. In your case remove the unportable VC cruft (`tmain`, `stdafx`) and add all includes.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I still get the same error.  When troubleshooting the problem,  I actually had that line commented that out.  Thanks for pointing that out.  It will at least save me some time troubleshooting after I solve the original problem.  
I'll removed the VC cruft and added the includes and fixed my omission.

Comment: @ThomasLann https://gist.github.com/4108222 This snippet compiles cleanly for me. The error must be in a part of the code you are not showing us.

Comment: Actually, that is the only code.  I believe the issue is I'm using libraries built by someone else.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just downloaded a fresh copy of boost 1.48.  I'm under the impression that asio doesn't need to link to a library even for it's dependencies.  Is this true?  I'm using VS2010
I just tried to compile it with that and I'm still getting the same issue.  It sounds like a compiler setting.  Can you specify what you used?

Comment: On VS Boost uses some auto-linking magic. I'm sorry, I can't help you with that. All I have done here is throw things into a file and sing the right gcc incantations including linker invocation. If you are sure it is a linker issue, post a new question and close this one.

Comment: I've sacrificed a few cups of coffee and said the necessary incantations to get it to work.  Alas,  MSVC won't do my bidding.  I don't think it is a linker issue because the errors happen during the Compile step during build.